# Using SSD as disk cache

Tags: linux, performance, filesystems, ssd

Is there software for Linux to use an SSD as disk cache?  I believe that Sun does something like this with ZFS, though not sure.  A quick search provides nothing suitable.  The goal would be to put frequently requested files on the SSD on-the-fly.  Since the SSD has more capacity than RAM for less money and better performance than hard disk, this should provide an efficient performance boost.

Comment: Are you sure SSD is nice for caching? As far as i know, SSD have rewrite limit of about 10000 cycles...

Comment: Good grief, modern flash SSDs are good for allegedly millions of cycles of writes.   See http://serverfault.com/questions/14189/reliability-of-ssd-drives for some further comments.  Furthermore, the server will likely be serving up a similar set of files frequently.

Comment: See also http://serverfault.com/questions/239808/ssd-for-swap-on-ubuntu-server/239817#239817, which is about swap, but the same caveats apply.

Comment: Actually it depends. And it isa shame i have to say that in a forum for professionals. There are terrible end user drives out there (25gb, 50gb per day allowed write budget) and thera re high end enterprise drives with 25+ complete rewrites per day(guaranteed over the 5 years you get warranty) and more, which is a LOT of data even for a cache. So, yes, they are adequate if you do not buy total crap cheapo stuff taht is meant for a low use laptop.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Facebook recently released a module for the Linux kernel called 'FlashCache' which can do exactly this:

http://github.com/facebook/flashcache

Answer (score 2):

Have you looked into Bcache? http://bcache.evilpiepirate.org/

I realize this is an old topic, hope this helps anyone else who might have arrived here like me with an ssd cache question.

Answer (score 1):

With SUN's ZFS, SSDs can be used as  L2ARC cache [1], using the zpool add cache command:

cache

```
A device used to cache storage pool data. A cache device cannot be cannot be configured as a mirror or raidz group. For more information, see the “Cache Devices” section.
```

I know nothing similar with Linux filesystems.
I don't know if it would be suitable, but one thing you may try would be to add swap on SSD and tune the `swapiness' Linux kernel parameter (sysctl vm.swapiness)

Comment: Swap on SSD won't help file performance - the kernel never uses swap space for page cache...

Answer (score 1):

I don't think there's a simple way to do this on Linux yet. ZFS is available as a userspace filesystem, but it's not very good. Some ZFS clones are on their way, but as far as I know nothing is ready for production.

Perhaps you could consider a BSD with ZFS?