# Is it sensible to use SLC swap as a RAM substitute on a VM host?

Tags: virtualization, memory, ssd, swap

I have a few oldish servers running virtual machines but they are limited to 16GB RAM and that limits the number of VMs I can run and the options for RDS.

I've added a RAID1 array of two Intel 311s: 20GB SLC SSDs, and configured them as swap on the host, in the hope that I can now more confidently over-allocate the available memory to the VMs.

So far so good in testing, but before I go any further I want to ask whether I'm missing any big reason why this is going to be a bad idea?

---

I should perhaps have mentioned that several of the VMs are used very intermittently but I can't reduce the memory they have as when they are active, it is needed.

Comment: possible duplicate of [SSD for swap on Ubuntu server](http://serverfault.com/questions/239808/ssd-for-swap-on-ubuntu-server)

Comment: Thanks Michael, the answers there are certainly helpful.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

No, it's not a good substitute for real RAM. SSD drives are an order of magnitude slower than RAM... But you know that :).

You also have issues with write-endurance of the drives under constrained memory conditions.

If the solution seems to work well in testing, then try using it... But know that the *right* approach is to equip your systems with the requisite amount RAM. If your systems cannot accommodate that amount of RAM, it's time to upgrade to modern hardware.

Comment: +1, thanks, write-endurance is my main concern. I am wondering if I should under-partition the array by, say, 4GB to improve endurance.

Comment: SLC is a good step. Underprovisioning is also an okay idea if its your only option. Try not to swap :) Consider a RAID level with data protection as well.

Comment: sorry, I meant RAID1 not RAID0—question edited.

Comment: Write-endurance for SLC is much less of a concern than MLC due to the lack of write-amplification SLC allows. That combined with underprovisioning should give multi-year endurance with an SLC drive purchased today.

Comment: *But* if the system is old enough to not accommodate > 16GB RAM, we all know that newer hardware will be the best bang-for-buck performance option. An SLC drive is wasted in that scenario.